# How to use fw1-loggrabber client

Tags: linux, checkpoint

While trying to run a fw1-leggrabber client as

```
fw1.loggrabber -l lea.conf --debug-level 3
```

i get the following debug message: [debug message](http://pastebin.com/9U6rggjv)

I have installed CheckPointR75.20 Splat. I created a new OPSEC Application using the SmartDashBoard Client. It generated a **Client DN**. After configuring the checkpoint server I got the **Server DN**. Now in the **lea.conf** file, i have the entries as

```
opsec_sic_name "CN=FinalShot,O=cpmodule..gy9quu"  (while creating OPSEC Application via Smart DashBoard)
lea_server opsec_entity_sic_name "o=cpmodule..gy9quu" (obtained from the server)
```

which is what i obtained from the above step.

The error i am getting is :

```
ERROR: SIC ERROR 111 - SIC Error for ssl_opsec: Peer sent wrong DN: cn=cp_mgmt,o=cpmodule..gy9quu
```

What might be the problem?

I saw that value **DN: cn=cp_mgmt,o=cpmodule..gy9quu** is in the section **MySicName** in the file **$CPDIR/registry/HKLM_registry.data**

And in the lea.conf file i'm supposed to put the server DN which is **o=cpmodule..gy9quu**. I dont know whats the problem here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following to solve the problem doing this:

I changed the line in the file:

```
$CPDIR/registry/HKLM_registry.data
```

containing

```
MySicName: cn=cp_mgmt,o=cpmodule..gy9quu
```

to

```
MySicName: o=cpmodule..gy9quu
```

Thanks anyways :)